# Multiple people speaking to a group

Tags: speech, terminology

A single person speaking to another person or a group is called a

- *monologue*

Multiple people speaking to each other is called a

- *dialogue*

How is it called when multiple people speak to another person/group without speaking with each other, like for example a presentation?

Is this still a *dialogue*? Or is it rather a

- *multilogue*

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to some word more sophisticated than "conversation", the British dictionary defines "*colloquium*" as an informal gathering for discussion.

> Wikipedia defines "multilogue" a conversation described as
>   many-to-many. The term is commonly used to describe the nature of
>   conversations and interactions using social media and collaborative
>   tools, such as social networking, online video, widgets for
>   syndication, wikis, message boards, forums, etc.

I never imagined that "multilogue" could be a noun. However, neither *multilogue*, *conversation* or *colloquium* convey the idea of multiple speakers not interacting together.